# Что лучше использовать для получения текущего времени в Java?

Tags: java, дата, datetime

Есть два способа получить текущее время - `new Date()` или `LocalDateTime.now()`.

Являются ли эти способы равнозначными или есть предпочтительный способ?

В программе нужно получить строку в зависимости от текущего времени. Какой из способов лучше и почему?

(1)

```java
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
```

(2)

```java
String fileName = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));
```

Comment: Класс `Date` устарел и к тому же является небезопасным с точки зрения потоков + имеет еще некоторые недостатки, поэтому использовать `LocalDateTime` всегда предпочтительнее. С парсингом даты то же самое, `SimpleDateFormat` - устаревший вариант, поэтому в любом случае лучше использовать классы из Java 8 DateTime API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с `new Date()` является устаревшим. Настоятельно рекомендуется использовать новую библиотеку для работы с датой и временем - java.time. Второй вариант, который вы привели - `LocalDateTime.now()` является более предпочитительным.